# Mysql import database

Tags: database, mysql, mysql-error-1049

I am new to mysql.I got a .sql file which I needed to import,so I searched online and got the below command.It worked perfectly.

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql -u root -p test3 < test3.sql
```

But when I said use test3 from mysql command line client,it gave me this error :

> ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'test3'

Am I missing some step?

Comment: check your .sql file to see what db are you importing

Comment: when you are "using" test3, are you using a different user who does not have the credentials to access test3?

Comment: I didnt get your point?

Comment: No I am working as root

Comment: Satya how to check the .sql file to see what db I am importing?

Comment: in the first few lines you must be seeing CREATE DATABASE command , that will tell you which database is being created

Comment: How to open the .sql file?I am using mysql command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you would need to create the database in MYSQL so that once you use the command, it is able to locate the name of the database

You can create the table using MYSQL developer tool or using the command line and then you can execute

```
mysql -u root -p test3 < test3.sql
```

Answer (score 4):

The database needs to exist, and be called from the command line using -D

so within MySQL try;

```
mysql> create database test3;
```

and back at the command prompt, try;

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql -u root -p -D test3 < test3.sql
```

Comment: But how was the original import successful without a database?!

Comment: I have no idea.I think it wasnt.I told you this was my first time so I thought it was successfull.

Comment: OK. I was about to suggest the same solution as @Gigline but did not because you said the import was successful. Anyway, good luck in your work.

Comment: I got error  
<code>
ERROR 1051 (42S02) at line 1: Unknown table 'wp_comment_notifier'
<code/>
I already created DB before

Answer (score 0):

You have not created test3 database yet. First create a test3 database & then try to import.